# JqueryUI Draggable not working in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, draggable, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using JQueryUI to help with the moveable items on this page:

http://www.hiredavewaring.com

If you scroll down, you'll see the png's that you can grab and move over my face to create a Mr. PotatoHead type effect.

I know it's not the prettiest code in the world, but it is working great on every browser, except Internet Explorer.

Does anyone know a fix to help these items become draggable in IE?

Here's the code without the Google Analytics or Meta:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/swagger.css" />

<!-- Draggable Pics -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<!-- end Draggable Pics -->

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper3">

  <div id="coverleftside1">
        <div id="dave3">
        <img src="images/dave3.png" alt="David Lee Waring, a Graphic and Web Designer in Orlando, FL">
        </div>
  </div>
    <div id="coverrightside1">

    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <div id="sig">
    <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="David Lee Waring, a Graphic and Web Designer in Orlando, FL">
    </div>
    <div id="nav3">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.hiredavewaring.com/index.html" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.hiredavewaring.com/about.html"  >About</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.hiredavewaring.com/design.html" >Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.hiredavewaring.com/contact.html"  >Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.hiredavewaring.com/blog" >Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Grafiti Time!  Click on an image below and drag it over Dave's face. Send us a screen shot of your favorite combination.</p>
    <a href="http://www.hiredavewaring.com"> Click Here to reset and start over. </a>
<div class="draggable">   
<div class="demo"><img src="images/funnyface/glassesnose.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo2"><img src="images/funnyface/beard1.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo3"><img src="images/funnyface/beard2.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo4"><img src="images/funnyface/beard3.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo5"><img src="images/funnyface/must1.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo6"><img src="images/funnyface/must2.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo7"><img src="images/funnyface/eyesangry.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo8"><img src="images/funnyface/eyescross.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo9"><img src="images/funnyface/eyesgoogle.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
<div class="demo10"><img src="images/funnyface/eyesscared.png" alt="Move me over Dave's Face!" ></div>
</div> 
<SCRIPT>
$(function(){
    $('.demo')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo2')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo3')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo4')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo5')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo6')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo7')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo8')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo9')
        .draggable();
});
$(function(){
    $('.demo10')
        .draggable();
});
</SCRIPT>
<!-- End Draggable -->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: WHat happens if you put 'type="text/javascript"' in the script tag that encloses the draggable calls?

Comment: You're using a very old version of jQuery and jQuery UI, consider upgrading.  Also, you could combine all your jQuery code into a single document.ready block, which likely won't fix any problems, but will certainly clean up your code.

Comment: Nothing happened when I tried that solution.

Comment: I'll update the JQuery versions now and report back shortly.  Thanks for the suggestion, MrOBrian.

Comment: That still didn't work.  Those PNG's are stuck right where they are.  I'll keep googling the issue to see if I can find another that is similar.

Comment: By IE, do you mean all versions of IE? Which have you tested?

Comment: Thank you, MrObrian.  That was the problem and you provided the solution.  I just didn't know enough about Jquery to take your advice properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would limit your code to a single `$(function(){});`.

```
$(function(){
    $('.demo').draggable();
    $('.demo2').draggable();
    $('.demo3').draggable();
    $('.demo4').draggable();
    $('.demo5').draggable();
    $('.demo6').draggable();
    $('.demo7').draggable();
    $('.demo8').draggable();
    $('.demo9').draggable();
    $('.demo10').draggable();
});
```

More importantly,  `draggable` **requires jQuery UI 1.8.6** or greater to work in IE9. There is also a [patch](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-sortable-and-draggable-do-not-work-in-ie9) available for older version, but I would really recommend upgrading.

Comment: Add a unique selector class and do the declaration like that : $('.draggable-element').each(function(){$(this).draggable();})

Comment: A very good suggestion.  You could even achieve this with the current markup, by doing something like `$('.draggable').children('div').each(function(){$(this).draggable();})`

Comment: This was the solution AND you cleaned up my code. Thank you! Cudos to MrObrian above, who also suggested this was the problem. I just didn't know enough about Jquery to follow his solution properly. –

Comment: I have added a column dynamically, and then its not working while we destroy  and again initialize after added new column. so please suggest us how we can do it also we are using jquery UI 1.11.4 version.