# Any idea why draggable div not released on mouse up in IE?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use [Jquery-UI draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) feature in my project.

It works perfect in Chrome.  It is also working in IE but it's buggy.

On IE When I click on 'draggable' div and start drug the div everything is OK. But when I release key (on `mouse up`) the 'draggble' div is not released and it continues to repeat mouse movements until the page reloads.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="z-index: 100; width: 50px!important; top: 200px;">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

And here is js bind method:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
```

Any idea why draggable div not released in IE?

**UPDATE:**
 I don't get any errors in the IE console.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is any error being reported in the IE console? That might get you started.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? jQuery UI officially supports IE11. Also check your document mode by opening developer tools.

Comment: @ice13 I use  IE11

Comment: I test your code in IE 11 but it work properly. Please this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ali_soltani/wrLypu4c/) in IE 11.

Comment: The instance when the release is not working for me on IE/edge is when I click the draggable element and move my cursor out of the draggable area and release the mouse key and then move the cursor back the to draggable area.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943344/jqueryui-draggable-not-working-in-ie

Comment: You might solve the problem with disabling compatibility mode in IE. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: It's working in IE10, it would be good if you provide how to reproduce or gif or fiddle.

Comment: can you create fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it happens because you try to open the page locally and IE blocks some features? Try to upload your files to a server and run them from there to see if the problem still persists.